# Unstable distribution problem when trying to install cMake

Tags: package-management

I have been trying to set up WSL so as to use VS code, but I encounter a few problems when trying to debug. It always tells me that the launch program does not exist.

I have been digging deeper, updating everything and I ran across this thing when trying to download cmake:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cmake : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

My main problem is that I cannot debug in vs code on the wsl. I am also using gdb.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Most Packages are built for a specific release, and thus it matters (exceptions do exist; eg. *snap* packages are built on one release but run on all; but your detail appears to be related to *deb* packages where release details are basic starting point, which you didn't provide).